# Do these characters have some sort of mapping function? "[1]", "[2]", "[3]",...,"[n]"

Tags: python, pandas, filter, character

I am using this line of code

```
df_mask = ~df[new_col_titles[:1]].apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('|'.join(filter_list), flags=re.IGNORECASE)).any(1)
```

to create a mask for my df. The filter list is

```
filter_list = ["[1]", "[2]", "[3]", "[4]", "[5]", "[6]", "[7]", "[8]","[9]",..."[n]"]
```

But I am having weird results I was hoping it would just filter the rows in column 0 of the df that have `[1]...[n]` in. But it doesn't it is also filtering rows that don't have those elements in. There is somewhat a pattern to it though. It will filter out rows that have numbers with "characters" by which i mean `£55, 2010), 55*, 55 *`

Can anyone explaine what is going on and if there is a workaround for this?

Comment: it's tough to visualize what's going on. Can you provide sample input and expected output? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: `[]` has special meaning in regular expressions. You need to escape it if you want to match it literally.

Comment: `[1]` matches the digit `1`, it doesn't match the square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match the items in filter list exactly, use `re.escape()` to escape the special characters. `[1]` is a regular expression that just matches the digit `1`, not the string `[1]`.

```
df_mask = ~df[new_col_titles[:1]].apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('|'.join(re.escape(f) for f in filter_list), flags=re.IGNORECASE)).any(1)
```

See [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)